# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'eth')

Tags: javascript, blockchain, ethereum, solidity, web3js

```
const  {web3js, myAccount} = require ('./utils')
const {bytecode} = require ('./contractartifact')

async function deploy() {
    web3js.eth.sendTransaction({
        from: myAccount.address,
        data: bytecode,
        gas: 800

    })
    .on('receipt', console.log)
}

deploy()
```

Error

> C:\Users\giris\getter-setter\deploy.js:9
> web3js.eth.sendTransaction({
> ^

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'eth')
> at deploy (C:\Users\giris\getter-setter\deploy.js:9:12)
> at Object. (C:\Users\giris\getter-setter\deploy.js:19:1)
> at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules  /cjs/loader:1153:10)
> at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
> at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
> at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
> at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47

Comment: What is the question here? You seem to have forgotten to ask one.

Answer (score 1):

Your import is incorrect here:

```
const {web3js, myAccount} = require ('./utils')
```

It should be:

```
const web3js = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider || "ws://localhost:8545");
```

Comment: Hey I am getting this error now   TypeError: The listener must be a function

Comment: That's a separate question and a different problem. If my answer solved your original issue, would you mind accepting it?

Comment: yeah, your answer is Somewhere solved my prob, but will you please help me with this error